# On fix time daily, toast message should be shown in Android

Tags: android, service

I want a simple toast message "Helloo everyone" to be display at 11:30a.m        daily.For this I have two classes MainActivity and AlarmReceiver
    I have tried many solutions but not found answer.
    Please help me.

Code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    int MID = 0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello everyone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

Mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.alarmmanagernotifcation.AlarmReceiver"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your alarm like this .

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Manifest Permissions.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
 <receiver android:name="com.example.alarmmanagernotifcation.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

[image]

Comment: No nothing happening.

Comment: How so.. Let me check it again.

Comment: Working great... Sharing you the screen shot

Comment: which device are u using for testing

Comment: Nexus 5X .. Nougat

Comment: Just use my code. I see you are using Georgian Calendar .. Simply use Calendar instance just like I mentioned.

Comment: yeah i have used your code,can u plz check my mainfest file

Comment: Remove this <receiver android:name="com.example.alarmmanagernotifcation.AlarmReceiver"/>. Receiver is always defined in application tag. Here com.example.alarmmanagernotifcation is the package name in which your receiver class is.